# Difference betweem WiFi basic rates and supported rates

Tags: wifi

I just got a shiny new Cisco AP, and for each data rate (1.0, 2.0, 5.5Mb/s, etc.), there are 3 options: Enabled, Disabled, or Required. The first two are pretty self explanatory, but what does "requiring" a data rate do? The AP has an option for "Best Throughput", which sets all of the data rates to Required, does this mean that the client has to support ALL data rates, or does it mean that it can match any one of the rates that are required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that "required" is the setting for multicast packets, while unicast can use any of the "enabled" data rates.

[source](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/access_point/12.3_8_JA/configuration/guide/s38rf.html#wp1101903)

Answer (score 0):

The client must support all basic (required) rates.